# Google Sheets Hightlight Top 10 Values AND Ignore Blank Cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, formatting, spreadsheet

I have been trying to figure out a conditional format rule that will highlight the top 5 values (The values are prices e.g. "$12,000.00") in a column. There are also blank cells throughout the column.

[image: Column Example]

I have tried making two rules. The first one being a rule that formats blank cells so they have no color. They were already not colored but I read that this will exempt the blank cells from the second rule. The first rule also preceded the second rule. For the second rule I have tried a couple of formulas.

One was: =$E$2>=LARGE($E$2:$E$1000,5)

Another was: =RANK($E$2,$E$2:$E$1000)<=5

I have tried looking through other stackoverflow posts but nothing had a solution I was needing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=$G11>=LARGE($G$11:$G$32,10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had to play around with it but your answer helped me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to format my column so that it was currency. Then the two rules worked.